# How do i store the chosen values after user input? The goal is to print out array2 as a receipt with all the chosen treatments when the user is done

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```java
String[][] array = {{"Checkup", "60"},
                    {"Repairing tooth", "150"},  
                    {"Cleaning", "30"}};  // Menu of treatments

String[] array2 = new String [10];  // New array that saves up to 10 elements(treatments)

int cost = 0;  
int treatment = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Control" + " " + "1");
System.out.println("Repair tooth:" + " " + "2");
System.out.println("Cleaning:" + " " + "3");

int n = array.length;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; i<n ; j++) {
        System.out.println();
        treatment = input.nextInt();
        if (treatment==1) {
            cost += Integer.parseInt(array[i][1]);
            System.out.print("Total cost so far: " + cost);
        }
        if (treatment==2) {
            cost += Integer.parseInt(array[i+1][1]);
            System.out.print("Total cost so far: " + cost);
        }
        if (treatment==3) {
            cost += Integer.parseInt(array[i+2][1]);
            System.out.print("Total cost so far: " + cost);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I move on from here? I figured that I have to store the input in the new array and exit the loop after 10 treatments or add an option to the user to print out the receipt when they're done.

The receipt needs to print all the chosen treatments along with the cost for each individual treatment. I will also need to add a variable to add a total amount for all the chosen treatments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is what you are trying to do, As the treatments are fixed so you can just index them as 0, 1, 2. One thing you can do is to make a hashmap in which you can store the treatment name and its cost (String,int) every time the user wants to enter.
Look at the code below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class treatment {

public static void main(String []args) {
    
    String[][] array = {{"Checkup", "60"},
                {"Repairing tooth", "150"},  
                {"Cleaning", "30"}};  // Menu of treatments

     // New array that saves up to 10 elements(treatments)
    HashMap<String, Integer> treat = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    int cost = 0;  
    int treatment = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



    int n = array.length;
    int i =0;
    char c = '\0';

    do {
        System.out.println("\n\nControl" + " " + "1");
        System.out.println("Repair tooth:" + " " + "2");
        System.out.println("Cleaning:" + " " + "3");
        System.out.println("Exit: " + "-1");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter treatment value (1, 2, 3): ");
        treatment = input.nextInt();

        if (treatment==1){ 
            i = 0;
            cost += Integer.parseInt(array[0][1]);
            System.out.println("\nTotal cost so far: " + cost);

        }
        else if (treatment==2) {
            i = 1;
            cost += Integer.parseInt(array[1][1]);
            System.out.println("\nTotal cost so far: " + cost);
        }
        else if (treatment==3) {
            i = 2;
            cost += Integer.parseInt(array[2][1]);
            System.out.println("\nTotal cost so far: " + cost);
        }
        treat.put(array[i][0], cost);

    } while (treatment != -1);

    System.out.println("Total COst is : " + cost);
    System.out.println("The treatements you opt for are:\n");
    System.out.println(treat);
    System.out.println("\n");
    
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Im not allowed to use HashMap for this one but i think i'll be able to continue with a similar solution :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped.